# Образование деепричастия

Tags: словообразование

Будьте добры, подскажите: перенесясь или перенесшись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настоящее время более употребительной является форма ***перенесясь***, а форма ***перенесшись*** можно отнести к устаревающей (в Нацкорпусе частотность 20:3).

1) **Немного грамматики (образование деепричастий совершенного вида)**

**Три основных варианта:**

Суффикс В используется при образовании деепричастий от основ **на гласную**: *устать – устав, растаять – растаяв, усвоить – усвоив.*

Суффикс ВШИ используется при образовании деепричастий от основ **на гласную от возвратных глаголов**: шелохнуться – шелохнувшись .

Суффикс ШИ используется при образовании деепричастий от основ **НА согласную**: потрясти – потрясши – суффикс ШИ.  Получается: **перенестись – перенесшись.**

**Частный вариант**

**Суффикс А/Я (замена суффикса В)**

Для образования деепричастий совершенного вида может использоваться основа простого будущего времени и **суффикс А/Я:** *прочтут – прочтя, найдут – найдя*.

В одних случаях эти деепричастия образуют вариантные формы: *заметив – заметя,*

В  других случаях они являются **более употребительными**, чем формы с суффиксами В/ВШИ/ШИ: *принеся, выйдя, зайдя, обретя, уведя.*

Получается: **перенестись – перенесясь.**

2) **Примеры**

Но **перенесясь** мысленно в XVIII век, мы увидели бы: шагнешь с Прусской улицы в сторону Десятинного монастыря ― стоит древняя церковь святого Якова. [В. Янин, 1984]

**Перенесшись** через восемь тысяч километров, эта далекая европейская война вдруг возникла во всей ее осязаемости здесь, в Азии ... [Константин Симонов. Далеко на востоке (Халхин-гольские записки) (1948-1968)]